# Different Subnet range, Same IP range,

Tags: networking, router, ip

I can Understand this:

Simple query. Just wondering, if I had one computer

PC-A

- IP:      192.168.0.10
- Subnet:  255.255.0.0

and another

PC-B

- IP:      192.168.0.15
- Subnet:  255.255.255.0

both on the same physical network, should I be able to ping PC-B from PC-A?

My question is what would the subnet look like if i had 7 PCs on the same IP?

Answer (score 2):

When you say "same physical network" are you saying they are all plugged into the same switch on the same VLAN?  If so, then yes - you should be able to ping each other as they would just assume they are in the same broadcast domain and respond to the ARPs.  It doesn't know anything about the other's subnet mask.

Long term as mentioned above - I'd suggest just getting them all with the same subnet mask.  No real good reason to have them different and it will cause issues if you ever need them to talk outside of that VLAN or with other items not addressed in that 192.168.0.x range.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Since '192.168.0.10"&'192.168.0.15" are on the same Network segment , they should be pingable each other.

(2)If there exists two Network segment, but share the same switch(on the same physical network) For example 192.168.1.0/24 and 192.168.2.0/24.
In this situation, You'll need a router to route between these two networks , since logically they are separate.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Ups, I was wrong on the first question... Danger Zone is right, in this case they are in the same broadcast domain, I overlooked that.

---

First question:

Simply speaking: a different subnet will "send" the ping to your router (default gate) for further "resolution". If your router "knows" how to access the "other" subnet it will work otherwise it won't.

Alternatively you can setup static routes or add a second IP (from the second subnet) to your NIC.

Second question:

IPs have to be unique, for a network to work. Theoretically you could use /32 or 255.255.255.255 depending on what you want to achieve.